# Why ML model produces different results despite random_state defined? And how to set global random seed for sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, feature-selection, performance

I have been running few ML models on same set of data for a binary classification problem with class proportion of 33:67.

I had the same algorithms and same set of hyperparamters during yesterday and today's run.

Please note that I also have the parameter `random_state` in each estimator function as shown below

```py
np.random.seed(42)
svm=SVC()  # i replace the estimator here for diff algos
svm_cv=GridSearchCV(svm,op_param_grid,cv=10,scoring='f1')
svm_cv.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
```

q1) Why does this change happens even when I have `random_state` configured?

q2) Is there anything else that I should do to reproduce the same results every time I run?

Please find below the results that are different? Here `auc-Y` denotes yesterday's run

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Not every seed is the same**.

Here is a definitive function that sets ALL of your seeds and you can expect complete reproducibility:

```py
def seed_everything(seed=42):
    """"
    Seed everything.
    """   
    random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

*You have to import torch, numpy etc.*

**UPDATE: How to set global randomseed for sklearn models:**

Given that sklearn does not have its own global random seed but uses the numpy random seed we can set it globally with the above :

```py
np.random.seed(seed)
```

Here is a little experiment for scipy library, analogous would be sklearn (generating random numbers-usually weights):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
print('Without seed')
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))

print('With the same seed')
np.random.seed(42) 
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))
np.random.seed(42) # reset the random seed back to 42
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))

print('Without seed')
np.random.seed(None)
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))
print(norm.rvs(100, size = 5))
```

outputing and confirming

> ```py
> Without seed
> [100.27042599 100.9258397  100.20903163  99.88255017  99.29165699]
> [100.53127275 100.17750482  98.38604284 100.74109598 101.54287085]
> With the same seed
> **[101.36242188 101.13410818 102.36307449  99.74043318  98.83044407]**
> **[101.36242188 101.13410818 102.36307449  99.74043318  98.83044407]**
> Without seed
> [101.2933838  100.52176902 101.38602156 100.72865231  99.02271004]
> [100.19080241  99.11010957  99.51578106 101.56403284 100.37350788]
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. So I shouldn't be using `random_state`? I only use `scikit-learn` and classic machine learning models like Linear and Logistic, SVM, RF,Boosting... No deep learning.

Comment: So I don't have to worry about `torch` etc right?

Comment: This s a general answer, but yes for your specific case sklearn suffices. Question is do you have any dependencies, I dont know your whole code

Comment: updated my code. can you advise now?

Comment: np.random.seed(seed) is numpy one that is used throughout sklearn

Comment: So I should define `np.random.seed(seed)` and assignthis seed in random_state?

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103210/discussion-between-the-great-and-noah-weber).

Comment: This solves the problem but leaves the question about why the random_state argument of scikit-learn models doesn't ensure repeatability unanswered.